# Deleting multiple fields form json nodes

Tags: javascript, python, json

everyone I have a relatively large json file (~10mb) in the following format:

```
[ {
    "obj1": [
              {
                "name":"Bob", 
                "last_name":"Marley",
                "instrument":"guitar"
              },
              {
                "name":"John", 
                "last_name":"Taylor",
                "instrument":"guitar"
              }
          ],
      "obj2": [
              {
                "name":"cool", 
                "last_name":"lastly",
                "instrument":"piano"
              },
              {
                "name":"chris", 
                "last_name":"jackson",
                "instrument":"guitar"
              }
          ]
]
```

How can I remove field **instrument** from both objects. Now my file has around 400000 lines of data, do how can I achieve this? I was searching for editors for vscode but I cannot find one that does this.

**UPDATE**

I will be running this operation once on the dataset I have so my intention is not to have any data loss otherwise speed and resource is not very important. However, I am trying NOT  to duplicate and rewrite the data if I can

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
var data = [{
  "obj1": [
      {
        "name":"Bob", 
        "last_name":"Marley",
        "instrument":"guitar"
      },
      {
        "name":"John", 
        "last_name":"Taylor",
        "instrument":"guitar"
      }
  ],
  "obj2": [
      {
        "name":"cool", 
        "last_name":"lastly",
        "instrument":"piano"
      },
      {
        "name":"chris", 
        "last_name":"jackson",
        "instrument":"guitar"
      }
  ]
}];

for(key in data[0])
{
  

  data[0][key] = data[0][key].map(item => ({name: item.name, last_name: item.last_name}))
}


console.log(data)
```

or

```js
var data = [{
  "obj1": [
      {
        "name":"Bob", 
        "last_name":"Marley",
        "instrument":"guitar"
      },
      {
        "name":"John", 
        "last_name":"Taylor",
        "instrument":"guitar"
      }
  ],
  "obj2": [
      {
        "name":"cool", 
        "last_name":"lastly",
        "instrument":"piano"
      },
      {
        "name":"chris", 
        "last_name":"jackson",
        "instrument":"guitar"
      }
  ]
}];

for(key in data[0])
{
  data[0][key].forEach(item => {
    delete item["instrument"]
  })
}


console.log(data)
```

Comment: Not the original data structre

Comment: Hello, I went with the first method and it was pretty simple and neat!

Answer (score 1):

Combine `Object.keys` `forEach` & `map`

```js
const input = [ {
    "obj1": [
              {
                "name":"Bob", 
                "last_name":"Marley",
                "instrument":"guitar"
              },
              {
                "name":"John", 
                "last_name":"Taylor",
                "instrument":"guitar"
              }
          ],
      "obj2": [
              {
                "name":"cool", 
                "last_name":"lastly",
                "instrument":"piano"
              },
              {
                "name":"chris", 
                "last_name":"jackson",
                "instrument":"guitar"
              }
          ]
}];
  
  const output = [{}];

Object.keys(input[0]).forEach((key) => {
       output[0][key] = input[0][key].map((e) => {
          delete e.instrument;
          return e;
       });
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: this could be cleaner by mutating the original object

Comment: Thats terrible! never manipulate the input/origianl.

Comment: Yes if the object is small, his object is 400000 lines long, duplicating it would make it slower and more resource intensive

Comment: We talk about 10mb... Dont go crazy over things that dosnt matter

Comment: Speed and low resource consumption always matters always matters haha...

Comment: It does, but keeping the original input is more important than the 0.003s you get  performance increasing. especially when you dont know what he want to do with the original data

Comment: Well its up to him, if he wants it copying, he can copy it.. Im sure the speed penalty is far higher than 0.003s, dont just quote figures without benchmarks.

Comment: As i sayed: it does! but keeping the original data is also important. in particular when you dont know what he wants to do with it...

Comment: I will be running this operation once on the dataset I have. So speed will not be important its a one time run. I will add this to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but @anon answer I felt it was just simple and so I decided to go with that, however, your method worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the correct answer. @anon assumed that the user would just pipe the input to output, which would have ended badly if there was any aggregation or any async operations. Image OP running a filter from express or just anything. If those assumptions were not correct(99% of the time they are not) then the accepted answer would be not only wrong but impossible to debug. Performance is NOT the most important metric in code; correctness and determinism is. The accepted solution isn't even the 'fastest' or most 'efficient' which it claims to be. @anon is correct by accident.

Comment: Friend of @Marc are you, very sad haha